# ImageView showing previous image view's data

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

I have the following view:
[image]

In which if I click on any ImageButton Shows respective image in full screen mode.For example if i click Black , it shows an Image view,like:[image]

also I have set background to fullscreen color for some imagebuttons like this:if I click pink it show plain pink color:

[image]

Upto now its all ok , If I click Black button first , And then I click pink, The image on the black is carried on to the layout with pink background,like this:

[image]

This is my problem, I want only Pink, Not the image in the foreground;

This is my XML file:

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#657383" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imv"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

<Button android:id="@+id/home"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/Back_Button"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image6"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image5"
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image7"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image5"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image8"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image6"
        android:background="#F52887"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

My .Java data is:

```
      private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 2500);



            if (v.getId() == R.id.image1) {
                iv.setBackground(null);
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            } else if(v.getId() == R.id.image2){
                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.kids_paint_hands);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image3){

                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_logo);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image4){

                iv.setBackground(null);
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image5){

                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image6){

                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image7){

                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.image8){

                iv.setBackground(null);

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                iv.clearFocus();
            }






        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any Help or suggestion?

Comment: post your code, you can set the visibility of the image to gone

Comment: Please add your code were you do switch of full screen in button click, so that we can see your mistake if any, and help you out.

Comment: @Pragnani:   Just updated my code with java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

First

```
ImageResource is different from the background Resource.

ImageResource is the foreground image, background resource is the background one.
```

You need to do like this

```
image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

to show transparent image instead of original one

Answer (score 1):

Your image Appear with background change because you are not resetting **ImageResource** attribute when you change the background color to pink or any other plain color because of which your previous image also do appears with new background.

To solve this you can either show image as a background instead of using ImageResource or you should remove the imageResource you have set for earlier (example :  iv.setImageResource(any transparent frame)).

Comment: Ya , i got that, But How?? The option iv.setImageResource() is only accepting , Remaining all are not accepting for Imageview.

Comment: Thankyou Rekha,.The above @Pragnani's method worked, yours also exact the same....